# Automorphisms of tensor product of two algebras $A \otimes B$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be two infinite dimensional $\mathbb{C}$-algebra. I am interested to find the automorphisms of $A \otimes B$.
My question is the following: If $f$ and $g$ are 2 automorphisms of $A$ and $B$ respectively, then will $f \otimes g$ be an automorphism of $A \otimes B$. If not, can we impose some conditions to make it an automorphism. My guess is that $f \otimes g$ will be a surjective map but I think injectivity is a problem.

Is there any way to get automorphisms of $A \otimes B$ from automorphisms of $A$ and $B$?

Comment: What does Pedersen "C*- algebras and their automorphism groups" have to say?

Comment: Can you please be a bit specific where to look? I have no idea of $C^*$-algebras.

Comment: That is what I asked you. If you can get the book look through it and see if there is any answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If $f$ and $g$ are automorphisms of $A$ and $B$, respectively, then $f \otimes g$ is indeed an automorphism of $A \otimes B$. Simply observe that $f^{-1} \otimes g^{-1}$ is a two-sided inverse of $f \otimes g$.

On the other hand, $f \otimes g$ isn't the sole form of automotphisms of $A \otimes B$. Simply let $A=B$ and the automorphism be $x \otimes y \mapsto y \otimes x$.